# File data get using PHP and HTML browse button

Tags: php, file

I am working with a PHP mailer in which template will be select with `HTML` browse button to get data to send mail.

i wants to get data in a variable ..
Not able to get data..

```
Warning: fopen(filename.txt) [function.fopen]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in PATH/php_mailer\sendmail.php on line 18
Cannot open file: filename.txt
```

**HTML**

```
   <form name="addtemplate"  id="addtemplate" method='POST' 
        action='' enctype="multipart/form-data">
            <table style="padding-left:100px;width:100%" border="0" cellspacing="10" cellpadding="0" id='addtemplate'>
                <span id='errfrmMsg'></span>
                <tbody>
                    <tr>
                        <td class="field_text">
                            Select Template
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <input name="template_file" type="file" class="template_file" id="template_file" required>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <input id="group_submit" value="Submit" type="submit" name='group_submit' />
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
    </form>
```

**PHP Code**

```
if(isset($_POST['group_submit'])){
        if ($_FILES["template_file"]["error"] > 0) {
            echo "Error: " . $_FILES["template_file"]["error"] . "<br>";
        }
        else {
            echo $templFile = $_FILES["template_file"]["name"] ;
            $templFileHandler = fopen($templFile, 'r') or die('Cannot open file:  '.$templFile); //open file for writing ('w','r','a')...
            echo $templFileData = fread($templFileHandler,filesize($templFile));
        }
    }
```

Comment: I have no idea what you're asking. Please clarify your question.

Comment: What is your exact question ?

Comment: Is there an error-message?

Comment: If your problem has been solved by using someone's answer, then please dont forget to mark it as accepted answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It doesn't work because `$_FILES['template_file']['name']` is the local file name that the browser sent to the server; to read the uploaded file you need `$_FILES['template_file']['tmp_name']` instead:

```
echo $templFile = $_FILES["template_file"]["tmp_name"] ;
echo $templFileData = file_get_contents($templFile);
```

I'm also using `file_get_contents()` which effectively replaces `fopen()`, `fread()` and `fclose()`. The above code doesn't check for failure on the part of `file_get_contents()` for any reason, this would:

```
if (false === ($templFileData = file_get_contents($_FILES["template_file"]["tmp_name"]))) {
    die("Cannot read from uploaded file");
}
// rest of your code
echo $templFileData;
```

Answer (score 4):

Please Replace $_FILES["template_file"]["name"] to $_FILES["template_file"]["tmp_name"]